# Organize SQL Server Stored Procedures in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

When working with code in Visual Studio I often find myself asking 'what stored procedure is this?'. Usually how I find the stored procedure is get the tableadapter.GetMethod name, locate and open the tableadapter (.xsd), highlight the query in the tableadaptor, go to properties and look for the commandtext to tell me what stored procedure it is. Then I go in to SQL Management Studio and view/edit the stored procedure. It's very long winded...

I know I have to be taking the long way to do this - there has to be an easier way. Normally I create a folder in AppCode for each table. Then I create a tableadapter and add in all of the queries that act on that table. Then I create Subs and Functions for all queries in that tableadapter in a .vb in the same folder. It would be great to be able to show a list of all stored procedures used in that tableadapter (and better yet, dbl click to get to the sp)

```
AppCode

    -SampleFolder
         -Sample.xsd
         -SampleOPS.vb
         -(show list of stored procedures used in this xsd)
```

I have looked at porting my website to a VS Database project; I have looked at creating schema's. I would like some suggestions on how to best organize my stored procs and speed up workflow.